# How do I use a Django variable as the width value in a style tag in HTML?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to use a Django variable as the percent width value in a style tag in HTML but it won't work.  I've noticed that it won't allow me to use curly braces {} at all in style tags, which doesn't make sense because from what I've seen online it should allow it.

I want it to be like this:

```
<div class="progress" style="height: 40px;">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:{{ value }}%">{{ value }}%</div>
</div>
```

for some reason when I do that this I immediately get an error for using curly braces {{}}:
[image: Image of my error]

The error is: "property value expected css(css-propertyvalueexpected)"

I also tried using this method:

```
{% with "width: "|add:value|add:"%" as percent_style %}
   <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style=style="{{ percent_style }}">{{ value }}%</div>
{% endwith %}
```

but it also did not work...

Thanks in advance.

Update:
I Disabled html validate styles in the Visual Studio Code settings and now I don't get the error in vs code and it works on the browser as well.
I was confused why it didn't work in the browser in the first place though so I enabled html validate styles again and it was still working in the browser despite the vs code error.  So I must have had a typo of sorts when I attempted to load it in the browser initially.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean here? Just that your editor shows those red squiggly lines? If you just ignore those and load the view in your browser, is the right HTML generated?

Comment: It also doesn't work when I try to load it in the browser

Comment: do this: instead of match_percentage_card.2 write  match_percentage_card[2]

Comment: You were right actually, it works.  I think I had a typo when I tried to load it in the browser initially.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your variable `match_percentage_card.2`
if 2 is a property then you have to use [] to access it
like this   `match_percentage_card[2]`

```
solution : do this: instead of match_percentage_card.2 write  match_percentage_card[2]
```